# Using custom jquery validation plugin in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I've been wondering how can we use custom validation plugins in `ASP.NET` `MVC 4`. I've searched on the web, but I've only found how to create new validation rules creating new attributes. The question here is another: There are lots of validation plugins out there, but how to use them in `ASP.NET MVC 4` ? By default the framework uses a simple validation that takes the message and displays it on the side of the field, but how to use another plugins ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which plugin do you want to implement?

Comment: How you use other plugins depends on the plugin in question, surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this this http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/custom-unobtrusive-jquery-validation-with-data-annotations-in-mvc-3/ and this http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#CustomValidator and  then try to make your own adaptation.

Comment: Thanks Felipe, I was really looking to something more "general" than for a specific plugin. I think the first article will do the job. Thanks again.